# Boxplot of a selected variable name

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How can I generate a boxplot for only "N" values across Variable 2 (7 observations).

```
Variable1 <- c(rep("E",7), rep("N",7),rep("L",7))
Variable2 <- c(rep(1:7, 3))
value <- c(12.44035, 11.98035333, 11.40821, 12.15833, 13.14826, 11.99339667, 12.17363, 4.073096, 3.946134667, 6.244152, 5.76892, 4.545772, 3.580206667, 2.879470667, 3.6912875, 3.501247, 2.684179, 3.06306, 3.364774, 4.485021333, 3.373649333)
dff <- data.frame(Variable1, Variable2, value)
```

I tried this but doesn't show what I want:

```
ggplot(dff, aes(x=Variable1$N, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

This would be my desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
dff %>% filter(Variable1=='N') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Variable2),y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
dff %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Variable2),y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, I got the first output, but for the second, how is code 2 specific to variable N?

Comment: @Ecg That is only an additional option. As you can see in your first option only `N` is considered but the values have only one point of data. I added in case you need it. The proper approach is first one, but you should have more data to get the boxes. I hope that was clear and sorry for any confusion!

Comment: I think I see what happens, there is only one value for N per observation. Let me change the dataframe and I think code 1 shdould work!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made an easy reproducible example but I miseed values, code 1 should work, will edit the post thanks!